# Is divergence proven with ratio test if result is $1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I have read about ratio test on the internet and it says if we got $1$ as result, we don't know whether the series converges or not.

So if I get $1$ as result in ratio test, I cannot say that this series diverges, right?

I will have to use something else then...? (direct comparison test & co.)

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: So I will have to use something else to prove it right?

Comment: Yes. The root test is more powerful. There's also *Duhamel's rule*.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) ;)

Comment: It is useful to note that the ratio test is really just a special kind of limit comparison test: namely, the ratio test basically tells you to compute $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right |$ and then do a comparison test with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left ( \frac{L+1}{2} \right )^n$. When $L<1$ this series is eventually bigger and is convergent, so the original sum converges; when $L>1$ this series is eventually smaller and is divergent, so the original sum diverges. When $L=1$ we cannot be sure how the two compare.

Comment: Too bad it's not defined... Anyway, this will always be my favorite way of proofing convergence :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The case when the limit is $1$ is undertermined. For example using the ratio test on both $$\sum_n \frac 1 n \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \sum_n \frac 1 {n^2}$$ will both result in a limit of $1$ but one diverges and the other converges. When the ratio test fails, often times the comparison test or the integral test work. The integral test is the one I normally go to next.

Comment: Very nice example, should say enough, tyvm! :)

Answer (score 3):

In case the ratio test fails because the limit is equal to $1$, you have a refinement with *Raabe-Duhamel*'s rule, which uses asymptotic analysis:

> Suppose $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1-\dfrac\alpha n+o\Bigl(\dfrac1n\Bigr)$. Then:
>
> - if $\alpha<1$, the series diverges;
> - if $\alpha>1$, the series converges;
> - if $\alpha=1$, we cannot conclude.

Comment: Bernard, +1 for the answer.  I thought this test was [Gauss's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html)

Comment: @Dr MV: I gave the name it has in France. There's also a Kummer test, but I never had to use it.